# Eclipse keep telling me remove final modifier of arraylist

Tags: java, android, interface, arraylist, final

I have a  `arrayList= new ArrayList<FriendsData>();` that is define inside an interface in my Base Activity.

```
public interface RequestUsers
    {
        ArrayList<FriendsData> arrayList    =  new ArrayList<FriendsData>();

    }
```

I already tried cleaning and restarting eclipse but nothing happens.

> Please expain why -1 I will remove my question if you think I am
>   stupid as compared to people here at STACKOVERFLOW.

Comment: Please post the exact code and message !

Comment: exact code is too big to post

Comment: What is the exact message given by Eclipse?

Comment: `remove invalid final modifier`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable in an interface can only be a constant (i.e. `static final`). Even so, it is oft considered poor style to have fields in interfaces.

An alternative is to have an `abstract class` as opposed to the `interface` if you genuinely need it in the superclass as opposed to individual extending instances.

Comment: My class already have a `BaseFragment Class`. I want use the arraylist both inside my fragment and model class.

Comment: Then surely composition would be more appropriate? Perhaps supplying each of the classes with the same `ArrayList` that you want them to share as a parameter in the constructor would be a nicer design?

Comment: The second class is an adapter class that is initialized only once . It is based on arraylist items that are generated at the runtime. Adapter has a listner that cause events according to arraylist.

Comment: Ok, so why can't you pass the same ArrayList to the other class that needs it in some shape or form, be it a parametrized constructor, mutators, etc?

Comment: here is the exact scenario. I have a `gridview` which has a layout inflated in it that contains a `imageview` and a `checkbox`. The `gridview` is initialized via separate adapter class. There are two listners for this `gridview` one is a `checkbox` that is inside the adapter class and other is the `gridview OnItemClickListener` and they both are accessing the same `arraylist`.

Comment: I can also make two more listners inside `adpater` and `fragment class` that can give me 'arraylist' changed event but that will ber cumbersome.